# regex for simple arithmetic expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've read other stackoverflow posts about a simple arithmetic expression regex, but none of them is working with my issue:

I need to validate this kind of expression: `"12+5.6-3.51-1.06"`,

I tried

```
const mathre = /(\d+(.)?\d*)([+-])?(\d+(.)?\d*)*/;
console.log("12+5.6-3.51-1.06".match(mathre));
```

but the result is `'12+5'`, and I can't figure why ?

Comment: You have to escape the `.` as `\.`

Comment: There are a lot of optional parts and the pattern is not anchored. Perhaps like this? `^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[-+][+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+$` https://regex101.com/r/9d46op/1/

Comment: Why *capture* `(.)?` instead of `\.?` I think you want `\.?` since `.` has special meaning. To represent it as "dot", you need to escape it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get 12.5 as a match, as there is not `/g` global flag, but if you would enable the global flag it will give partial matches as there are no anchors `^` and `$` in the pattern validating the whole string.

The `[+-]` is only matched once, which should be repeated to match it multiple times.

Currently the pattern will match `1+2+3` but it will also match `1a1+2b2` as the dot is not escaped and can match any character (use `\.` to match it literally).

For starting with digits and optional decimal parts and repeating 1 or more times a `+` or `-`:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[-+]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ovQTEb/1)

If the values can start with optional plus and minus and can also be decimals without leading digits:

```
^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[-+][+-]?\d*\.?\d+)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[+-]?` Optional `+` or `-`
- `\d*\.\d+` Match *+ digits with optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[-+]` Match a `+` or `-`
  - `[+-]?\d*\.\d+` Match an optional `+` or `-` 0+ digits and optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `)+` Close the noncapture group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single `+` or `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GqmycX/1)

Comment: `-12+5.6-3.51-1.06` or likewise `+12+5.6-3.51-1.06` does not validate.

Comment: also `.2+5.6-3.51-1.06` does not validate (actually any `0. ...`-float value written like `.digits` within the string) even though it should.

Comment: @aestheticsData ... ah ok, then I was not carefully enough reading the requirements and I apologize.

Comment: @PeterSeliger your comment was right :-) but not in my specs indeed.

Comment: @PeterSeliger The answer has a second pattern that can validate those values. https://regex101.com/r/7uHNhR/1

Comment: this regex is not working with "3" or "3.1"

Comment: @aestheticsData It does work for those numbers, see https://regex101.com/r/GQcj78/1 If you also want to match only numbers `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[-+]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$` see https://regex101.com/r/UwaTwf/1

Answer (score 1):

You would try to use this solution for PCRE compatible RegExp engine:

```
^(?:(-?\d+(?:[\.,]{1}\d)?)[+-]?)*(?1)$
```

- `^` Start of String
- `(?:` Non capture group ng1
- `(-?\d+(?:[\.,]{1}\d)?)` Pattern for digit with or without start
  "-" and with "." or "," in the middle, matches 1 or 1.1 or 1,1
  (Matching group 1)
- `[+-]?` Pattern for "+" or "-"
- `)*` Says
  that group ng1 might to repeat 0 or more times
- `(?1)` Says that
  it must be a digit in the end of pattern by reference to the first subpattern
- `$` End of string

As JS does not support recursive reference, you may use full version instead:

```
/^(?:(-?\d+(?:[\.,]{1}\d)?)[+-]?)*(-?\d+(?:[\.,]{1}\d)?)$/gm
```